# form nodejs http server, in browser we get 'domain' did not send any Data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

NOTE: this issue is happening in one linux machine and I have tested this in other linux machines, there it is working fine.

I created http server using nodejs http package as below:

DOES NOT WORK

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 9001;

const printContent = function (content) {
    console.log('***** Content of File STARTS *****\n');
    console.log(content);
    console.log('\n*** Content of file: ENDS *****');
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // printContent('html');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.end('Hello');   
    }, 0);
    
    console.log('*** function ends ***');
        
});

// server.timeout = 5000;
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

In this case response ends with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

but when I remove setTimeout it works fine.
WORKS FINE:

```
     const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { 
        printContent('Hello');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.end('Hello');   
    });
   server.listen(9001);
```

This is very strange behaviour I am facing that If i make something asyn does not work.

Comment: Edited so that I make little more sense, here res does not have status function nad I want to use forementioned "http" object only. I ran this in more than tow machine works fine, but there is one specific machine where its not working and works only when there is no setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas Morris... thanks for the quick reply.

I am posting this answer so that if any one faces this issue should not spend as much time as I did.

Since it was not working in one machine and was working in another. So I thought of replacing the node binary and after I did this, the above code started working. The node binary itself was corrupt.

I have spent around 4 days to reach to this solution...really weird :)

Comment: Nice find can you clarify what you mean by a node binary. As when you run the server I presume you call node app.js(or whaterver file) and that runs the server. So what is the binary?

Comment: Binary means node command itself, it has been installed somewhere, in my case it was inside /usr/bin/node so I downloaded the same version of node from nodejs.org and replaced the current node and it started working...I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using res.send not end so something like:

```
res.status(200).send("Hello");
```

Also I recommend using postman for debugging.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I tried testing using postman and I am getting Error: socket hang up...there

Comment: Try sending a test response like I listed above and see if that works.

Comment: res object does not have status function...I tried this first then I tested what error postman is giving